# Drawer Menu and Tabs working together

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tabs

I want to implement a bottom tabs with fragment tab host and a Drawer menu in my Action bar activity. Tabs or a drawer menu item open the same fragment.

So can any one help me out for this ..

My Code is as..

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    item.setVisible(false);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

private void selectItemFromDrawer(final int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Search();
//                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            break;

        case 1:

            fragment = new Featured();
//                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new Saved();
//                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Popular();
//               mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
            break;
        case 4:


            break;
        default:

            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

        if (position == 0) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MipTags");
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(MenuItem[position]);
        }

        // Close the drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
    } else {

        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

private void InitView() {

    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(this);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


    mTabHost.setup(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.mainContent);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_down)),Search.class, null);


    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_down)), Featured.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_down)), Saved.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_down)), Popular.class, null);
//        mTabHost.addTab(
//                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab5").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_down)), null, null);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            int i = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            selectItemFromDrawer(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure but let us know what have you tried yourself!

Comment: My Code is as below. I implemented Drawer menu as well as Tab Host but when i click tab or a menu item fragment became overlap.